# Why is the li moving below the image after i set it to inline-block?

Tags: html, css, navbar, nav

I am trying to create a nav bar and i don't know why i am facing this problem :
Trying to set the `li` within the `ul` as `inline-block` works, but it is moving the whole list below the image i am using as a logo.
Can someone explain why is this happening and how to fix it?
https://codepen.io/rou-teodor/pen/QWNrVNZ

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.logo {
  width: 150px;
  position: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

#nav-bar {
  background-color: yellow;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

#nav-bar li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header id="header">
      <nav id="nav-bar">
        <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/Gyq8iOFxCVu1elwlR_1-GxK3u-TUWFFlOQSqrfDZgAHetn8z2IwFTVlfxbFKi22xFMo50VuCSigKfek8gVmIspvxC-TIr0Ve0a5eke9v72M3k9xkxmhrsdxYpiqgnFm6Sg" alt="" class="logo" />
        <ul>
          <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">acasa</a></li>
          <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">despre</a></li>
          <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">produse</a></li>
          <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">cumpara</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <img src="cover.jpeg" alt="" id="header-img" />
      <p></p>
    </header>

    <section class="products">
      <div class="product1"></div>
      <div class="product2"></div>
      <div class="product3"></div>
    </section>

    <div class="form">
      <!-- Formular cumparare -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `vertical-align: middle` on your `.logo` class instead of **position**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add `display: flex;align-items: center;` to align vertically center the navbar :)

```
#nav-bar {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The navbar isn't below the logo, it's just on the same line. The reason for the way it looks is that the logo image is quite high (select it in the browser tools to see that)

To have the navbar vertically centered to the logo, you can add `display: flex;` and `align-items: center;` to the CSS rule for `#nav-bar`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.logo {
  width: 150px;
  position: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

#nav-bar {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

#nav-bar li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <header id="header">
    <nav id="nav-bar">
      <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/Gyq8iOFxCVu1elwlR_1-GxK3u-TUWFFlOQSqrfDZgAHetn8z2IwFTVlfxbFKi22xFMo50VuCSigKfek8gVmIspvxC-TIr0Ve0a5eke9v72M3k9xkxmhrsdxYpiqgnFm6Sg" alt="" class="logo" />
      <ul>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">acasa</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">despre</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">produse</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">cumpara</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <img src="cover.jpeg" alt="" id="header-img" />
    <p></p>
  </header>

  <section class="products">
    <div class="product1"></div>
    <div class="product2"></div>
    <div class="product3"></div>
  </section>

  <div class="form">
    <!-- Formular cumparare -->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```